# Change TextView text on value change

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

I'm trying to do something like this after clicking a button:

```
case R.id.bcheckConnection:
        if (IPok()) {
            PlcState.ErrPlc = false;
            Constant.adressIpPlc = adresIp.getText().toString();

            final ProgressDialog dialog =     ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "", "Trying to connect...");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    timeout = network.testConnection(Constant.adressIpPlc, 102, 20000);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).start();

            if (timeout > -1) {
                PlcState.ErrPlc = false;

                stanPolaczenia.setText("Connection established. Timeout = ");
                stanTimeout.setText(Long.toString(timeout));
                currentIp.setText(Constant.adressIpPlc);

            } else {
                PlcState.ErrPlc = true;
                stanPolaczenia.setText("Error");
                stanTimeout.setText("");
                currentIp.setText(Constant.adressIpPlc);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Wrong IP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;
```

So is it possible to change text AFTER thread stops running?

Comment: Why not use an `AsyncTask`? It has `onPostExecute()`, which runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use `AsyncTask`. It makes more sense.

Comment: Is it possible then to change value od TxtView which was referenced (findViewById) in onCreate method?

Comment: Yes, keep it as a member variable in your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Thread.join()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) to block the current thread until the given thread is finished:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // Do something
    }
});
myThread.start();

// Do some things

// and block current thread until myThread is finished
myThread.join();

// Continue execution after myThread got finished
```

**Edit**: As @Eric already mentions in the question comments: for your (example) situation it seems to make more sense to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It has two events (that are called on the UI thread), so you can update your UI with progress updates and when the task finished. For an `AsyncTask` example see: [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: Does that not defeat the whole purpose of doing something on another thread?

Comment: Before waiting on `myTHread` you can do all kind of things. Call `join()` after you are done and *really* need `myThread` to be finished. In my example, it indeed defaults the purpose of threads completely yes. I have updated my answer to make this (more) clear.